# Remove max values from a row if outside criteria & recalculate again

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with readings from four sensors measured every 5 minutes. The requirement is to

- calculate the average of the four sensors
- if a value is more than 3% different to the average, reject that value
- calculate the average of the remaining 3 sensors
- if a value is more than 3% different to the average, reject that value
- repeat

Example:

```
    PCU_1   PCU_2   PCU_3   PCU_4
50  777.742 718.338 742.445 747.016
51  836.361 903.235 879.436 978.934
52  727.017 724.114 793.942 775.843
53  605.709 659.761 640.930 698.307
54  110.978 109.853 106.536 104.108
55  711.227 717.215 807.651 768.889
56  876.883 907.998 856.678 868.977
57  951.960 952.145 997.779 993.696
58  611.169 662.214 710.009 872.859
59  967.444 982.002 990.523 993.374
```

Note that removing the entire row is not permitted. The index is a timestamp, if that helps.

I have code working which rejects all values that are more than 3%, but I am struggling to work out the recursive requirement.

```
# drop irradiance values which are wrong (more than 3% from the mean)
irrad_mean = df[irrad_cols].mean(axis=1)   # calculate the average
df_irrad_normalised = df[irrad_cols].div(irrad_mean, axis='rows')  # normalise
df_irrad_normalised = df_irrad_normalised.sub(1) 
bool_mask = abs(df_irrad_normalised) < 0.03  # mask values outside limit
divisors = bool_mask.sum(axis='columns')
true_irrad = bool_mask.mul(df_irrad).sum(axis='columns').div(divisors)
df['Mean Irradiance (discarded outliers)'] = true_irrad
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = df.columns
# You shouldn't ever have to do the check more than n-1 times.
for _ in range(len(cols)-1):
    # Get the row's mean as a helper column.
    df['means'] = df[cols].mean(axis=1)
    for col in cols:
        # Calculate difference between col and mean, mark if > 0.03
        m = df[[col, 'means']].pct_change(axis=1)['means'].abs().gt(0.03)
        # Replace marked values with nans.
        df.loc[m, col] = np.nan

df = df[cols]
df
```

Output:

```
      PCU_1    PCU_2    PCU_3    PCU_4
50      NaN      NaN  742.445  747.016
51      NaN  903.235  879.436      NaN
52      NaN      NaN      NaN  775.843
53      NaN  659.761  640.930      NaN
54  110.978  109.853  106.536      NaN
55      NaN      NaN      NaN  768.889
56  876.883      NaN  856.678  868.977
57  951.960  952.145  997.779  993.696
58      NaN      NaN  710.009      NaN
59  967.444  982.002  990.523  993.374
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some testing but it seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but it required a tweak to ensure the 2nd and subsequent passes re-calculate the mean of the remaining values.

```
cols = df.columns
# You shouldn't ever have to do the check more than n-1 times.
for _ in range(len(cols)-1):
    # Get the row's mean as a helper column.
    df['means'] = df[cols].mean(axis=1)
    for col in cols:
        # Calculate difference between col and mean, mark if > 0.03
        m = df[[col, 'means']].pct_change(axis=1)['means'].abs().gt(0.03)
        # Replace marked values with nans.
        df.loc[m, col] = np.nan
        df['means'] = df[cols].mean(axis=1)

df = df[cols]
df
```

Thanks again for your help.